# Drools compiler not finding external JARs when the Java compiler finds them okay

Tags: java, jar, external, drools

I am using Eclipse Kepler and Drools 6.0.1 Final. The basic installation works and I can
run rules and even see a refactor apply to both Java and DRL files. JRE 7. I can add more
detail if needed - but I don't think it affects my core question.

My problem occurs when I want to incorporate an existing project. This is in NetBeans so I want
to just pull in the jars. I have added them to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries. This works
fine and executes correctly from the java side (I've added the external jars in a variety of different ways and
nothing changes the problem I am getting). However, the problem I have appears to be that the Drools compiler
is not finding the same Jars and hence raises Drools errors (different symbol, listed as "Drools Error"
in the Problems list). I have spent ages trying to figure out where I might reference this external Jar so
Drools can see it - but zilch success. If I disable Drools builder in the list of builders (and clear
the existing problems) then no more are raised. With Drools builder enabled, I get "xxx cannot be resolved to a type"
or "Error importing xxx" etc. It's like the Drools compiler either has its own idea of classpath
or similar, or just isn't bothering to scan something.

How does the drools compiler decide on where to find libraries or external jars? All the behaviour I 
am getting points to it doing it differently to Java compilation - which feels to be a bad way for
it to behave.

Any pointers most welcome.

Comment: Adding Jars to an Eclipse project classpath isn't going to do anything useful. It just makes sure that Eclipse can see them. If you're on Drools 6, then dependencies are resolved using Maven. Just reference the projects in your pom.xml.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the pointer. I have some Maven learning to do now then :) But I probably ought to know more about Maven anyway.

Comment: Oh yes ... Drools 6 really does only work well if you play nicely with Maven. :)

Comment: Ok, progress but still the same issue. I manually installed my existing jars as maven artifacts in my local repository, Made a new Eclipse project (think I've tried making a maven project then migrate to drools and make a drools and migrate to maven - both with same result). Maven and dependencies are doing their job - my code compiles and runs and this is without using classpath to get my existing libraries in to the equation. But still the drools compiler is flagging the same errors against my usages of things that are being pulled in from maven dependencies. Any thoughts please?

Comment: You get these errors when running `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Using "Maven clean" and "Maven install" from the "Run As" menu for the project does not generate these errors. They happen either from the "Clean" option for the Project or when typing changes in and saving the file. They need manually clearing so sometimes I miss what triggers them. Disabling Drools from Properties->Builders hides the errors. Almost like there's some bit of "dot connecting" I've not done yet.

Comment: That implies that your Maven config is correct but your Eclipse project has not been set up correctly. Or possibly the Eclipse Maven plugin is messing up, which it always seems to do for me. My tip would be to disable the "maven nature" of the project if you have set it up and then run `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` from the command line to get the `maven-eclipse-plugin` to generate your Eclipse project properties.

Comment: I've gone around the houses. Fresh Eclipse install. Rebuilt local .m2 repository. Even tried 6.1.0.Beta4. Nothing makes Drools compiler find items in the pom.xml. And Drools can find kie-api even when accidentally missed from pom.xml

Everything points to Drools compiler using something other than pom.xml to "know" what it depends on. The fact I can run stuff correctly says pom.xml is working.

Totally confused :(

Comment: Hmm. Looks like a plain bug. What a waste of 5 days :( http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Compilation-errors-in-Drools-examples-td4027650.html Especially the comment "I have the same problem. It seems like the drool eclipse plugin can't recognize third party classes (any jar files besides those within JRE runtime and Drools runtime). Despite of the error messages, you can execute the java application correctly." precisely matches my experiences. I'll await getting a fixed version. But thanks for responding and trying to point me in useful directions - I understand Maven better now.

Comment: Got it! http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Compilation-errors-in-Drools-examples-td4027650.html It's a plain damned bug in Drools. To quote one of the posters "I have the same problem. It seems like the drool eclipse plugin can't recognize third party classes (any jar files besides those within JRE runtime and Drools runtime). Despite of the error messages, you can execute the java application correctly." Precisely what I got. Have gone to http://downloads.jboss.org/drools/release/snapshot/6.1.x/ and grab latest updatesite and installed that in a clean Kepler Eclipse and it works!!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution/workaround! It's definitely worth making sure you're on the latest version if you're playing with 6.x. There are plenty of bugs being uncovered. You might find also it useful to follow the mailing list, as that tends to be where bugs and other unusual behaviour get reported, as there are a lot of folks trying to explore 6.x at the moment.